# Error on creating Report Model :Data extension does not support model generation

Tags: reporting-services, reports

I'm trying to create a Report builder Model using a SP Custom List as Datasource. 
But it returns me the following error:

> Data extension does not support model generation. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ModelGenerationNotSupportedException:
>   Data extension does not support model generation.

Comment: I'd love an answer to this issue!